# How To Generate PDF Documents from CSS 3 in Java

Tags: java, pdf, css, pdf-generation

I'm currently working on a project which involves turning complex structured images and text and converting them into a PDF using Java. My first instinct was to create HTML/CSS which represented the way in which the data should be outputted, and then using a Java library to converted that HTML/CSS into a PDF. In doing research, I haven't found any good solutions that take into account CSS 3 properties like border-radius, box-shadow, and transform: rotate. I've looked into iText w/ Flying Saucer, and PD4ML.

Does anyone know of a good free or commercial product that is up to date and supports such new CSS technologies?

Or is it possible that I'm just going down the wrong path attempting to use CSS/HTML to begin with?

Comment: Have you looked into XML-FOP?

Comment: exactly what i am looking for but still havent found the solution

Answer (score 1):

I don't think html/css is a good idea. Making your images and formatting work with html/css is one pain, then converting that to PDF is another.

PDF supports embedding images and formatting text, so why don't you use it directly? Generating images with any Java tool/lib and printing PDF with iText or iReport can't be harder than doing this to html/css alone.

Answer (score 1):

HTML/CSS sounds like unnecessary overhead. Since your data is 'structured' images and text, if its easily converted to XML you might have some luck with Apache FOP

Comment: A friend of mine has recently said: Turning a non-XML problem into an XML problem is the last thing I want. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use headless OpenOffice with JODConverter (http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter) to open a temporary HTML file, and then save to Export to PDF from headless OpenOffice. As long as you have a relatively simple HTML/CSS file, you should be OK. I've used this quite a bit, and it seems reliable.

I don't know the specifics to CSS3 in my recommendation. I've heard rumors of using headless Firefox for something like that, but you would be stepping outside of Java. Since I haven't personally done that, can't offer too much more commentary on it.

Comment: Forgot to mention the sensibility aspect. Personally, I'd try to avoid creating an HTML doc for the sole purpose of converting to CSS. It'd work, but not ideal, and have a lot of overhead.